# Can't resolve Library dependencies

Tags: c, cmake, platformio

I got a platformio project. I want to include a library on a specific commit.

So, I used the command line interface of platformio:

```
platformio lib --storage-dir lib install https://github.com/th0br0/iota.lib.c.git#fd193af198628759da39cf6a930fa352c012ba4b
```

That works fine. I just can now include the library on the following way:

```
#include <iota/iota.h>
```

But this library has also dependencies and these dependencies got not resolved. So, I also imported the dependencies of the dependencies:

```
platformio lib --storage-dir lib install https://github.com/th0br0/ccurl.git#c8cd1f87def10ebf0f31483dcc42c3b95473c982
```

In comparison to the other library, I cannot include this library via

```
#include <curl.h>
```

When I deploy my project, I see the second library will not included into the build project

```
Library Dependency Graph ( [BITLY_LINK] )
|-- <iota.lib.c> #31d0a89
|-- <avr-enc28j60>
```

[BITLY_LINK] pints to http://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/librarymanager/ldf.html

My CMakeLists: https://pastebin.com/eeY756SN

My CMakeListsPrivate: https://pastebin.com/14W23BxZ

I included the following to CMakeListsPrivate:

```
include_directories("$ENV{HOME}/git/c/BlinkExample/lib/iota.lib.c/external/ccurl/src/lib")
```

My IDE is now able to find curl.h, but I still get the compiler error.

```
src/main.c:7:18: fatal error: curl.h: No such file or directory
```

The complete output: https://pastebin.com/wb0BBdfx

Comment: PlatformIO is supposed to look in the {project-home}/lib directory when searching for include files. Did you put both dependencies under that directory.

Comment: Also, PlatformIO uses the `library.json` file in the *library* root to identify library dependencies. You could try to submit a PR to the primary library https://github.com/th0br0 with a `library.json` file that referred to the other library.